# Remove "?" from NSString IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am trying to remove all symbols from a string, it works fine with below code for all symbols except "?".

```
NSString *newString = self.titleString;

NSArray *characters = @[@"<", @"!", @"@", @"#", @"$", @"%", @"^", @"&", @"*", @"(", @")", @",", @"_", @"+", @"|", @">", @"?", @" "];

for (NSString *str in characters) {
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:str withString:@""];
}
```

Comment: I tried your given code sniped its working fine even with ? it's working it removed from string.i used following string with your code @"Hello 1234?>()?"and got out put "Hello1234". so please can you tell which string u used  create problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` with the regular expression option, `NSRegularExpressionSearch`:

```
NSString *output = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[<>!@#$%^&*(),_+?| ]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

You can also take advantage of other regular expression features, e.g. replace all non-letter characters:

```
NSString *output = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\P{L}" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

or not A-Z:

```
NSString *output = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^a-zA-Z]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

It just depends upon precisely what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all characters in a single call using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSString *string = self.titleString;
NSError *error = nil;
// Prepare the regular expression that matches any of your characters
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[<>!@#$%^&*(),_+?| ]"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
// Replace all matches with an empty string
string  = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: While it's not explicit in the OP's question, how can regex catch punctuation in different languages?

Comment: @StephenFurlani I don't think regex can do that: even POSIX `[:punct:]` has a pre-defined set of characters.

Comment: If you want to match punctuation, it's `\\p{P}`. But that won't cover many of the OP's characters (e.g. currency symbols), which would be covered by `\\p{S}`. And then whitespace, with `\\s` or `\\p{Z}`. Frankly, in these situations, it's often safer to approach from the other direction, i.e. what symbols are permitted (e.g. `[^a-zA-Z]` or `\\P{L}`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `?` like that: "\?". Otherwise it won't work properly. `?` only means in regex stands for 0 or 1 occurences and so you have to say to objective-c that it is a real char you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for editing user text you might want to consider using a union of more than one `NSCharacterSet` - this will help it be more language-friendly when you localize/internationalize your app.

```
NSString *myInputText = @"asd;jkfhals@$%^%$&1asldiguhd";
NSCharacterSet *nonAlphanumeric = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invert];
NSArray *parts = [myInputText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonAlphanumeric];
NSArray *mySafeOutputText = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

It's a little non-intuitive to use the `components` method, but unfortunately Apple doesn't provide a `stringByReplacingCharactersInSet:` method. :(